# Get a list(without spaces) of all values in range that contain "keyword"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have a range of values how can I extract all values that contain a specific word?

For example:

[image]

Is there anything better then

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$21,0)+2&":A21"),
 MATCH("*"&$C$1&"*",INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$21,0)+2&":A21"),0)),"")
```

I would prefer Formulas over VBA but feel free to post VBA solutions too.

Comment: Are you able to tweak the initial list, say by inserting another column?

Comment: Also having a column for the `indirect` search will eliminate you doing this twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I trick I've learnt will help here and **no VBA** is required. Put this in D2 and drag down:

```
{=INDEX(A:A,
  SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$C$1&"*",$A$2:$A$11)),
           ROW($A$2:$A$11),
           MAX(ROW($A$2:$A$11))+1)
        ,ROW()-1))}
```

**Note: This is an array formula and needs to be entered with <kbd>Control + Shift + Enter</kbd>.**

*Explanation:*

1. The `index(<arr>, <nbr>)` will get the value of the row we find;
2. The `search(<string>, <arr>)` will find all values in the array that match and is the reason for the array formula;
3. The `if` function will return the row number if a match exists and if not set a default row number, in this case the last one + 1; and
4. Most importantly the `small(<arr>, <n-th>)` function will now return the nth smallest row number starting, in this case the cell has to be in row 2 otherwise the `-1` needs to be altered.

**Non-VBA Pivots initiated by VBA:**

I've found the pivot tables bring a large improvement in performance:

1. Add your Pivot as normal but put the location of D1.
2. You can use the in-built *contains* or *search* ability

   [image]
3. **Or** use VBA on the `Worksheet`

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

       If Target.Address = "$C$1" Then
           With Me.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("name")
               .ClearAllFilters
               .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=Target
           End With
       End If

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Trying your code crashed my computer multiple times, running 8 gb rams and I7 quad core. When tested on a small range such as 10-50 cells it seemed to work fine, even if slow. But when entering it in 100,000 cels references 600,000 cells. It simply froze excel, even when leaving it unattended for a bit, On the same Ranges my formula calculates in 1 minute and 3 seconds. But just to get an accurate test, I modified your formula to `=INDEX($A$1:$A$50,
  SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$C$1&"*",$A$1:$A$50)),
           ROW($A$1:$A$50),
           MAX(ROW($A$1:$A$50))+1),ROW()-1))`

Comment: I then copied that down 50 cell and ran a loop on it 100,000 times, this took 5 minutes 18 seconds, i ran mine on the same ranges and got a time of 2 minutes 52 seconds. I believe this is because your references EVERY cell in the look up range EVERYTIME where mine dynamically reduces the number of cells it look in from the last match down, **possibly** ???

Comment: I think you have limited choices but to use VBA. I'll look into my code for improvements. I like the idea of non VBA.

Comment: My code gets the job done. I am not a fan of VBA when a faster formula can get the job done. I think if I can find a way to rid my formula of the volatile ` indirect ` function it could make it much faster.

Comment: I agree completely VBA only where required!

Comment: added another choice, **vba** and **non vba** in one. I'd be interested in your performance.

Comment: Alright, so while this will probably be great in many uses. Set up time on it might be a little much for simple cases, Adding table setting range, setting the properties and orientation of field, removing row labels and grand totals (if needed) then filtering. And second is that fact that a pivot table is going to manipulate the data, so in the case where I use this code as a way to look up duplicates, it will fail as it only shows single values (unless i further modify the table) and second it will sort all the data. Still this is a good solution in many cases. So +1.